# Trouble with HomeBrew

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I'm having trouble searching for the list of all casks when I run the command for it.

```sh
brew search --casks
```

I get the error you see in the picture.

> **Error:** Invalid usage: This command requires at least 1 text or regex argument.

[image: Screenshot of console]

If anyone has had similar problems please share.

Comment: You're not entering any tex or regex to search. Try `brew search --casks test`

Comment: Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930492

Answer (score 5):

You need at least one string to search for.

```
$ brew search --casks fire
==> Casks
firefly                    firealpaca                 firestorm
firefox-beta               firebase-admin             firestormos
firefox-developer-edition  firebird-emu               fireworks
firefox-esr                firecamp                   multifirefox
firefox-nightly            firefox ✔                  spitfire-audio
```

If you **really need** to find all available casks, you can use an empty arg like this:

```sh
brew search --casks ''
```